# Why isn't the 'strcat' function working?

Tags: c, string, strcat

I am trying to concatenate arrays from a structure using `strcat`. My code looks as follows:

```
int main(){

//Implementation of Search table Tree

struct searchTable
{
    char first[10];
    int first_id;
    char second[10];
    int second_id;
    char third[10];
    int third_id;
    char fourth[10];
    int fourth_id;
    char fifth[10];
    int fifth_id;

}input[5]= {
        {"ABC", 101},
        {"CAB",102},
        {"ACB",103},
        {"AAC",104},
        {"CCB",105}
};
char join[100]={0};

strcat(join, input[0].first);
strcat(join, input[1].second);
strcat(join, input[2].third);
strcat(join, input[3].fourth);
strcat(join, input[4].fifth);

printf("%s", join);
```

Here the output instead of giving me

> ABCCABACBAACCCB

gives me just

> ABC

Could somebody tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Just asking, do you have `string.h` included?

Comment: @SouravGhosh: Yes. I have string.h and stdio.h included

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Write instead

```
strcat(join, input[0].first);
strcat(join, input[1].first);
strcat(join, input[2].first);
strcat(join, input[3].first);
strcat(join, input[4].first);
```

Using these initializers

```
//...
}input[5]= {
        {"ABC", 101},
        {"CAB",102},
        {"ACB",103},
        {"AAC",104},
        {"CCB",105}
};
```

you explicitly initialized only the first two data members of each element of the array that is `first` and `first_id`. All other data members were zero-initialized.

If you want to use exactly your statements with `strcat`

```
strcat(join, input[0].first);
strcat(join, input[1].second);
strcat(join, input[2].third);
strcat(join, input[3].fourth);
strcat(join, input[4].fifth);
```

then initialize the array the following way

```
struct searchTable
{
    char first[10];
    int first_id;
    char second[10];
    int second_id;
    char third[10];
    int third_id;
    char fourth[10];
    int fourth_id;
    char fifth[10];
    int fifth_id;

}input[5]= {
        { .first = "ABC", .first_id = 101 },
        { .second = "CAB", .second_id = 102 },
        { .third = "ACB", .third_id = 103 },
        { .fourth = "AAC", .fourth_id = 104 },
        { .fifth = "CCB", .fifth_id = 105 }
};
```

In this case the output will look like

```
ABCCABACBAACCCB
```

Comment: Thank you for that help. I was wondering if I could implement this with a for loop? Is this possible?

Comment: @Goldengirl I do not imagine how it can be done with structure data members defined like it is shown in your example.

Answer (score 4):

The problem here is, while initializing at definition time, you're only initializing the first two member variables of each `input[n]` element (Check the number of initializer supplied). So, later, while doing

```
strcat(join, input[1].second);
strcat(join, input[2].third);
strcat(join, input[3].fourth);
strcat(join, input[4].fifth);
```

all the `second`, `third`, `fourth` and `fifth` member variables for `input[n]` elements are initialized to `0` or null-pointer, as the array definition is global.

The output is correct and it is the expected output for this code.

---

Having said that, the recommended signature of `main()` is `int main(int argc, char *argv[])` or at least, `int main(void)`.

Answer (score 3):

You are declared the structure with ten members

```
struct searchTable
{
    char first[10];
    int first_id;
    char second[10];
    int second_id;
    char third[10];
    int third_id;
    char fourth[10];
    int fourth_id;
    char fifth[10];
    int fifth_id;
}
```

While assigning the value you are mentioning the two values, So first two values will be assigned. Rest of the variables will be null.

```
strcat(join, input[1].second);
strcat(join, input[2].third);
strcat(join, input[3].fourth);
strcat(join, input[4].fifth);
```

If you do like this, you will get this output, as like you expected.

```
    strcat(join, input[0].first);
    strcat(join, input[1].first);
    strcat(join, input[2].first);
    strcat(join, input[3].first);
    strcat(join, input[4].first);
```

Comment: "_If you do like this, you will get this output, as like you expected._" -- Nope.

Answer (score 2):

Your initializer does not cover all members of the `struct searchTable`, just first two members for each element of the `input` array. The others are initialized with zeros implicitely. That way:

```
strcat(join, input[1].second);
strcat(join, input[2].third);
...
```

concatenates with empty strings, as all of these are treated as zero-length, because they are starting with `'\0'` (or `NUL` in ASCII) *null character*. In other words:

```
strlen(input[1].second) == 0
strlen(input[2].third) == 0
...
```

Answer (score 2):

```
input[5]= {
        {"ABC", 101},
        {"CAB",102},
        {"ACB",103},
        {"AAC",104},
        {"CCB",105}
};
```

You are always initializing the first two members . `i.e first and first_id`

**so do replace all with input[0].first. that will work for sure .**

> Happy Coding !!!!!!!